# maximum number of edges in NodeXl

Tags: excel, graph, social-networking

Im trying to use NodeXL to analyse network which has 250 000 rows and 2000000 edges. 
The problem is that excel only allows me to import from csv in 2 columns ~1000000 rows  (each row is one edge).

Is there any possibility to analyse network with bigger count of rows using nodeXL ?

thanks for any help and advice, 
bye

Answer (score 5):

NodeXL is designed for micro and meso scale graphs and does not (yet) support mega and giga scale graphs.

NodeXL does scale in part in proportion to the amount of RAM, Disk, and CPU available.

That said, 250K nodes and 2M edges is beyond what NodeXL can do today.  You may want to explore slicing the existing graph into more manageable sub-region that can fit < 10K nodes and < 100K edges.

Regards,

Marc (from Team NodeXL)
Support discussions are available at http://nodexl.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

FYI, i am handling around 3500 nodes with 30,000 edges. It generates a network graph but too slow to handle data and other visualization.

Using parallels with Mac pro (6 core, 32gb ram).